# Bring jsp form page after previous submit (java spring)

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

New to spring (and HTML/forms etc for that matter) and been stuck on this problem for long time.

So I want to have a front page where you enter a username. Then click submit, and takes you to a dashboard (ultimately, there will be a page with a list of connected users, a load of submit buttons to send predefined messages out - using qpid jms).

The front page is fine, but I click submit and I get an error (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dashboardModel' available as request attribute)
This only happens if I have a form:form in dashboard.jsp. I literally have no idea how to fix this and have tried everything I can find. My code is simple, and is just modified from a tutorial, so here it is:

login.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Page:</h2>
<form:form modelAttribute="loginModel" method="POST"
    action="/HelloWeb/dashboard">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="username">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
public class Login {
private String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
}
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "loginModel", new Login());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedIn", method = RequestMethod.POST) //never actually used
public String loggedIn(@ModelAttribute("Login") Login login, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", login.getUsername());

    return "dashboard";
}
}
```

dashboard.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>DASHBOARD</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Dashboard</td>
        <td>DASHBOARD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>${username}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>variable</td>
        <td>${variable}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form:form modelAttribute="dashboardModel" method="POST"
    action="/HelloWeb/dashboard">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="variable">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="variable" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class Dashboard {
private String variable;

public String getVariable() {
    return variable;
}
public void setVariable(String variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
}
}
```

DashboardController.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class DashboardController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView dashboard() {
    return new ModelAndView("dashboard", "dashboardModel", new Dashboard());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addVariable(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Dashboard dashboard,
        ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("variable", dashboard.getVariable());
    return "dashboard";
}
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="loginModel" method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/dashboard">
                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedIn", method = RequestMethod.POST) //never actually used
public String loggedIn(@ModelAttribute("Login") Login login, ModelMap model) {
                                        ^^^^^
```

The `modelAttribute` value on `form:form` element and the `@ModelAttribute` argument should be the same.

I mean:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedIn", method = RequestMethod.POST) //never actually used
public String loggedIn(@ModelAttribute("loginModel") Login login, ModelMap model) {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Edit:**

Also, the form part should be like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="dashboardModel" method="POST" action="/loggedIn.htm">
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: It doesn't actually seem to matter what the value there is - I have no idea why though. E.g. you can see from the original tutorial (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm) has got "SpringWeb" as the @ModelAttribute, however is just the default "command" for the other, so they don't match.

Comment: Sorry,  which form?  The one in login.jsp or dashboard.jsp?